# Accessing TCP/IP routing information from a .NET application

Tags: c#, routes, network-programming, tcp

I need to check if a TCP/IP route already exists from my application and add the route if it doesn't.
Now I'm running the

```
route add <destination network ip address> MASK <mask> <gateway ip address>
```

with a Process.Start() and that's fine for me.
However, as I'm elevating the route command with a "runas" verb, I need to check first if the route is already configured in order to avoid running the elevated command again.

Does anybody know how to get the TCP/IP routing information using .NET Framework? (I don't want to run route print with a Process.Start() and parse the output)

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to rely on IpHlpApi.Dll

[Here is a tutorial on how to use it with P/Invoke](http://bertjansen.spaces.live.com/Blog/cns!D9B33D4A940B6FFD!192.entry?wa=wsignin1.0&sa=358703673)

Comment: Thanks for the link, I think it's the solution but my question is, why that information is not available to the .NET framework directly?

Comment: I think it is possible to use System.Management to access WMI. Also, I guess a pure .NET solution would only be a wrapper around the IpHlpApi.dll so they didn't bother

Comment: Yeah, you're right, but having a wrapper is better than nothing :P, thank you very much for your answer.